# Что такое парциальные шаблоны и как они работают в RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
#depot/app/views/carts/_cart.html.erb
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>
  <%= render(cart.line_items) %> #  как работает?

  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

#depot/app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb
<tr>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

`_cart.html.erb` вызывается из layout:  `<%= render @cart %>`

Что происходит в этом коде, как работают парциальные шаблоны?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При вызове `render` на `ActiveModel`-совместимом объекте (**одной** записи) у него вызывается метод `.to_partial_path`. Обычно он возвращает строку вида `"вещи/вещь"`. У вас это работает для `@cart` (возвращает, вероятно, `carts/cart`). И рисует (renders) его, связав рисуемый объект с одноимённой (с шаблоном) переменной `вещь` (у вас `cart`).

---

[С коллекциями механизм работает практически так же](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections), но **для её элементов**, полученных через `.each`. Просто отрисовывает их подряд. Ваш `render(cart.line_items)` это почти то же, что и:

```
render("line_items/line_item", collection: cart.line_items)
```

...только какие представления использовать, он выяснит сам, спросив у элементов. Есть интересный связанный с этим трюк: это позволяет по-быстрому отрисовывать коллекцию из элементов **разных типов**, выдав соответствующий шаблон каждому из них.

Comment: Почему использвуется название `_articles.html.erb`, а не в единсвенном числе `_article.html.erb`? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Comment: @jisecayeyo опечатка, скорее всего. Можете проверить у себя.